# Wrong dimensions during printing from SketchUp

Tags: print-production, sketchup

I'm modeling in SketchUp and having issues printing output with correct dimensions. For example, if I download some precise model from the Internet (as a knob for music instrument) - it prints right away, I convert STL to GCODE in Cura and everything fits perfectly. But when I do model in SketchUp and convert it to GCODE in Cura at the print it shrinks model to a smaller size. Please help me figure out why my dimensions are incorrect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

STL is unitless format. You must inform your printing software what the numbers in your STL file mean. Your downloaded STLs obviously use Cura's default units.

I have not Cura, but the problem has been in the past a blight with DXFs which didn't carry dimension units.

Comment: I checked CURA inside out and didn't find any settings about that..Not sure why downloaded models are compatible and other - no. I just created 10x10x10mm solid box and CURA shows correct dimensions. It perfectly fits on grid and scale shows these dimensions. But when I print - it's smaller. If I change the scale to 150% then it's almost expected result

Comment: @FredOroskoDias Now it's clear we do not know does Cura output the final g-code with wrong dimensions or does your printer driver interpret it wrongly. Try to check the g-code file in alternative software. I cannot give better than guesses. Sorry.

Comment: Restored my printer defaults from manufacturer and now works :) Magic!